# Octave: functions doesn't return more than one value

Tags: function, return-value, octave

In order to address to my problem, let's consider the most basic function

```
function [x, z] = main ()
  x = 1;
  z = 2;
endfunction
```

When I execute this function the output is

> ans =  1

whereas I should have gotten something like

```
ans = 1

      2
```

So why is this happening? What is the problem?

Comment: Please read [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.3/Defining-Functions.html) link.

Comment: @kiner_shah I checked that link before, but couldn't find anything useful to solve my problem.

Comment: If I tried `[k, v] = main()`, then it assigns `1` to `k` and `2` to `v`

Comment: @kiner_shah Ok, thanks a lot.If you like, post this as an answer so that I can accept.

Comment: I think you should wait for even better answer! ;-)

Comment: @kiner_shah you are right, we should wait.

Comment: Why do you think you should get your second ans? This is not how Octave or Matlab works. If you want to return a vector the do somethink like `x = [1;2];` in your main function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you need multiple values out of an Octave (or MATLAB) function, you need to explicitly ask for all of them. If you provide no output arguments, the default behavior is to provide only the first output (unless the user explicitly specifies that there should be no outputs `varargout = {}`) and assign it to the variable `ans`.

So, if you want two outputs you need to explicitly ask for *both* of them

```
[x, z] = main()
```

If you want your function to return an array of `x` and `z` when only one output is provided, you can use `nargout` to detect how many output arguments were requested and modify the return values appropriately

```
function [x, z] = main()

    x = 1;
    z = 2;

    % If there is one (or zero) outputs, put both outputs in the first output, otherwise
    % return two outputs
    if nargout < 1
        x = [x; z];
    end
endfunction
```

And then from outside of your function

```
main()
%   1   
%   2

output = main()
%   1
%   2

[x, z] = main()
%   x = 1
%   z = 2
```